# Conversion from ibpp to pqxx in C++ project

Tags: c++, postgresql, firebird, libpqxx

I have a C++ code which uses Firebird (driver ibpp), and I need to make a conversion to PostgreSQL (pqxx is used). Main file which I need to change is [this one](http://pastebin.com/utrWb4Cp). I started, but now I have difficulties.

```
while (st->Fetch())
{
    st->Get(1, tName);
    st->Get(2, fieldName);
    st->Get(3, fieldType);

    if (tName != tableName)
        continue;

    result.push_back(DbField(fieldName, fieldType, ""));
 }
```

I have no idea how to rewrite it using pqxx. I've rewrite some piece of code in pqxx, u can see it [here](http://pastebin.com/JzB6vmSK).
So can u help me with this fragment?

I've just started working with SQL and it could be great, if someone will explain me how does ibpp code-works. And if u left some links with big pqxx-examples, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBPP fragment executes the query `sql1` and the given loop goes through the resulting table rows and pushes them all to the `result` which is probably kind of vector.

The analogue Postgres code would be

```
vector<tuple<string, string, string>> result_set;
pqxx::work txn(*conn);
pqxx::result res = txn.exec("SELECT TRIM(RL.RDB$RELATION_NAME), TRIM(FR.RDB$FIELD_NAME), FS.RDB$FIELD_TYPE ...");
for (unsigned i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
{
    string first = res[i][0].as<string>("");
    string second = res[i][1].as<string>("");
    string third = res[i][2].as<string>("");
    result_set.push_back(make_tuple(provider, oper, priority));
}
```

The query of course should be completed, since it is truncated here.